# Storyboard, does not recognize UIControl actions anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

This project runs and compiles fine, but in all storyboards if I was on a UIControl (such as a UIButton) interface builder doesn't seems able to detect it as the correct class.
As you can see in the connection inspector the action. [image] The connection is spotted with an exclamation mark.
The identity inspector shows the class correctly.
I already tried to fully clean the project, even derived data.
Project build and runs fine but I can't connect actions anymore.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you copy this UIButton from some other interface in your project or dragged from object library?

Comment: where is userPressedDIs.. selector define?

Comment: Is defined in the correct class, this problem started this morning everything where fine

Comment: @MilanGupta they are taken from the library

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this seems a bug in Xcode.
To reproduce it you just need to make a protocol and make a `UIButton` conform to it.

This test few lines, breaks everything and you are no longer able to create and make connections from IB and the source file:

```
protocol TestProcol {
    var test: String { get set }
}

extension UIButton: TestProcol {
    var test: String {
        set(val) {
            titleLabel?.text = val
        }
        get {
            return (titleLabel?.text!)!
        }
    }
}
```